# C select is overwriting timeout value

Tags: sockets, select, timeout

In a very simple C program, using `select()` to check any new read data on a socket, when I use the optional `timeout` parameter, it is being overwritten by `select()`. It looks like it resets it to values of seconds and microseconds it actually waited, so when data is coming sooner than the timeout, it will have much smaller values, leading to smaller and smaller timeouts unless `timeout` is reset, when `select()` is called in a loop.

I could not find any information on this behavior in `select()` description. I am using Linux Ubuntu 18.04 in my testing. It looks like I have to reset the `timeout` value every time before calling `select()` to keep the same timeout?

The code snippet is this:

```
void *main_udp_loop(void *arg)
{
    struct UDP_CTX *ctx = (UDP_CTX*)arg;
    
    fd_set readfds = {};

    struct sockaddr peer_addr = { 0 };

    int peer_addr_len = sizeof(peer_addr);

    while (1)
    {
        struct timeval timeout;
        timeout.tv_sec = 0;
        timeout.tv_usec = 850000; // wait 0.85 second.

        FD_ZERO(&readfds); 

        FD_SET(ctx->udp_socketfd, &readfds);
        
        int activity = select( ctx->udp_socketfd + 1 , &readfds , NULL , NULL , &timeout);  

        if ((activity < 0) && (errno != EINTR))  
        {  
            printf("Select error: Exiting main thread\n");
            return NULL;
        }  

        if (timeout.tv_usec != 850000)
        {
            printf ("Timeout changed: %ld %ld\n", (long)timeout.tv_sec, (long)timeout.tv_usec);
        }

        if (activity == 0) 
        {
            printf ("No activity from select: %ld \n", (long)time(0));
            continue;
        }
        ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is documented behavior in the Linux [`select()` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html):

> **On Linux, `select()` modifies *timeout* to reflect the amount of time not slept;** most other implementations do not do this.  (POSIX.1 permits either behavior.)  This causes problems both when Linux code which reads *timeout* is ported to other operating systems, and when code is ported to Linux that reuses a *struct timeval* for multiple `select()`s in a loop without reinitializing it.  **Consider *timeout* to be undefined after `select()` returns.**

So, yes, you have to reset the `timeout` value every time you call `select()`.